# windows 10 ssh proxycommand: "posix_spawn: No such file or directory"

Tags: ssh, proxy, windows-10

I use Windows10 and I need to use a jumphost to get to my Linux servers. Thus I have configured my `.ssh\config` like so:

```
Host jumphost
HostName jumphost.server.local

Host server*.server.local
ProxyCommand  ssh jumphost netcat -w 120 %h %p
```

But when I run `ssh server01.server.local -v` (dash-v for verbose) I get the following error:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\admin/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\admin/ssh/config line 70: Applying options for server*.server.local
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh jumphost netcat -w 120 server01.server.local 22
CreateProcessW failed error:2
posix_spawn: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As per [this bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1185), the fix is to use a full path. So this is the correct line in the `.ssh/config`:

```
  ProxyCommand  C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe jumphost netcat -w 120 %h %p
```

For further development see this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/18

Comment: Thank you thank you- just likely saved me hours of frustration after updating to 1809

Comment: If you don't mind installing/running third party software, MobaXterm (free for personal use, no online activation needed) includes a ssh version that works correctly with "-J" parameter. 

Also it can correctly make use of Windows Subsystem for Linux which also can be upgraded to an ubuntu version (bionic) which contains a correctly working "-J" ssh version. Both variants allow running directly from command line without having to alter configuration files

Comment: [continuation from previous comment] The first option also includes native ssh-agent communication with putty's pageant.exe so it can use the pageant loaded keys.

Comment: Is it possible to make this work without a config file (using only -J and -o parameters)?

Answer (score 33):

#### TL;DR

The `ProxyCommand` should invoke ssh with `.exe` extension, for example:

```
ProxyCommand ssh.exe -q -W %h:%p yyy
```

#### The long(?) story

Running `ssh -vvv XXX` shows:

```
debug3: spawning "C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh -q -W XXX:22 YYY"
CreateProcessW failed error:2
posix_spawn: No such file or directory
```

According to `CreateProcess` document on MSDN, I guess `posix_spawn` is calling `CreateProcess` in a way that `lpApplicationName` argument must be exact and absolute path. After specifying the `.exe` suffix, it seems to be fixed.

Comment: this is the better answer.

Answer (score 4):

I got same error but it was because of DISPLAY environment variable set to some value. Once you unset that environment variable, the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has to do with a bug in the OpenSSH Windows implementaiton. This bug is fixed with release 8.1.0.0. Detailed instructions on how to patch the version can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/18#issuecomment-507258777)

Answer (score 0):

Since netcat is not available on a default system, the following two entries in the .ssh/config will do the trick (assuming that the local username and the remote username are distinct).

`login.bar` : system to login 
`jump.bar`  : jumphost
`<username>`  : remote user name on login.bar and jump.bar (if they are distinct <jumpuser>@jump.bar is needed). If you omit <username>@ in front of jump.bar the local username is taken.

a)

```
Host foo
User <username>
HostName login.bar
ProxyCommand C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -q -X -W %h:%p <username>@jump.bar
```

b)

```
Host foo
User <username>
HostName login.bar
ProxyCommand C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -Y <username>@jump.bar -W %h:%p
```

In both cases login to login.bar with: `ssh foo`